# How to create an alias for .. to mean cd .. in macOS shell

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I often find myself typing `cd..` (which results in `-bash: cd“: command not found`) in stead of `cd ..`
So would like to add an alias for this in my .bashrc or better yet, I would like an alias for `..` to mean `cd ..`

I can't get it to work however; I tried several options:

`alias ..=cd ..` results in `alias ..='cd'`

`alias ..='cd ..'` results in `alias ..=''cd'`

Also escaping the dots in various ways doesn't work:

`alias ..=cd \.\.` results in `alias ..='cd'`

`alias ..=cd '\.\.'` results in alias `..='cd'`

What is correct way to do this right?

Comment: Why don't you create an alias for `cd..`?

Comment: I tried this; it results in the same trouble with the dots...

Comment: Zsh does that by default ;)

Comment: More info: if I type in the alias definition in the shell itself, it works. It only won't work if I do the setting in .bashrc

Comment: @LakshayGarg: I think you have to explicitly enable it in zsh (for instance in your .zshrc), by `set -j` (*AUTO_CD*).

Comment: me using this function defined in `~/.profile`: `cd..() { cd ..; }`

Comment: This actually works where all other suggestions have failed me, Thanks!!!

Comment: This also works: `..() { cd ..; }`

Comment: @willemx while the `..()` works, I **strongly** recommending NOT using the `..` as an bash function name. It _could_ cause debugging problems is some scripting scenarios. The `cd..` is solving the "missing space" problem in the `cd ..` - without side effects. :)

Comment: @jm666 Ok, will do. Also going to try and install a new bash version.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on linux (Ubuntu 16.04) with bash v4.3.46. I believe it won't be any different for macOS.

```
alias '..'='cd ..'
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does NOT work for me (macOS Sierra 10.12.3)

Comment: @willemx: The version of your operating system is irrelevant here. We need to know, what shell you are using. From the error message you posted, I conclude that it is *bash*, so it would make sense telling us the version of bash (it's in `$BASH_VERSION`).

Comment: bash: 3.2.57(1)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are interested in solutions working for bash.

If you want to solve this with an alias, you have to use a name which starts with a letter, for instance

```
alias up='cd ..'
```

Maybe more interesting for you would perhaps a general solution, where typing any directory name would cd to this directory. You can do it by placing into your .bashrc the command

```
shopt -s autocd
```

After this, `..` would bring you one directory up, `~` would bring you to your home direcory and `aunt/bertie` would cd you right to your aunt.

Comment: -bash: shopt: autocd: invalid shell option name

Comment: @willemx because the default shell in `macOS` is stupidly old bash. The first `v3.2` is released 11years ago. The current is `v4.4`. Me using [macports](http://macports.org) for installing opensource packages. Unfortunately, you need to have downloaded the Apple Xcode - development environment.

Comment: @willemx: That's why I told you to tell us the BASH_VERSION. It doesn't make sense to blindly type commands without knowing whether they are appropriate for your platform....